# Best alternative for multiple nested switch statements?

Tags: javascript, switch-statement

I have a JavaScript function with multiple nested switch case which is a total mess. The function has been extended over the past few months, now I would like to restructure the code.
In every case, a different value should be pushed to an already existing var.

Here is an example of my code:

```
switch(var1){
    case 1:
        switch(var2){
            case 0:
                switch(var3){
                    case 'test':
                        switch(i){
                            case 0: endresult.push({id: i, content: '123'}); break;
                            case 2: endresult.push({id: i, content: '124'}); break;
                        }
                        break;
                    default:
                        endresult.push({id: i, content: '125'}); break;
                }
                break;
            case 1:
                endresult.push({id: i, content: '126'}); break;
        }
        break;
    case 2:
        switch(var2){
            case 0:
                switch(i){
                    case 0: endresult.push({id: i, content: '127'}); break;
                    case 2: endresult.push({id: i, content: '128'}); break;
                }
                break;
            case 1:
                switch(i){
                    case 0: endresult.push({id: i, content: '128'}); break;
                    case 2: endresult.push({id: i, content: '129'}); break;
                }
                break;
        }
        break;
}
```

What would be the best way to rewrite this?

Comment: can you please show how you are calling this

Comment: I would consider using an object for this. Although it might be a bit finicky working out the `default` option

Comment: do you have unknown values who are not in the structure, where you want to do nothing?

Comment: This is essentially a bunch of conditions , e.g., it can be re-written as `if (var1 ==1 && var2 == 0 & var3 == 'test' && i == 0)`. The presence of so many seemingly disparate flags puts the design into question. It probably doesn't need a re-write as much as re-design to simplify the logic altogether. It's hard to say exactly *how* to be redesigned without a fuller picture, though. Also, this might be a good question for [SoftwareEngineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 3):

Have a map of all possible variations and it's values:

```
// Key is composite of `"" + var1 + "_" + var2 + "_" + i` and trimmed `_` from back

let tree = {
    '1_0_test_0': '123',
    '1_0_test_2': '124',
    '1_0_test': '125',
    '1_0_1': '126',
    ...
}

let key = ("" + var1 + var2 + i).replace(/_{2,}|_+$/, '');

if (typeof tree[key] !== 'undefined') {
    endresult.push({id: i, content: tree[key]});
}
```

Comment: but where's var 3?

Comment: @ACD Missed in answer, but concept is clear I think. Should add it too.

Comment: it won't work if it goes to case 2 and var3 has value. and would lose the purpose if you add condition `if (var1 == 2) var3 = ''`;

Answer (score 1):

Your concern is readability right? You probably need to split your code a bit. And use variable names instead of 0 and 1. Also you need to provide more details. Like can it go beyond 0 and 1 to 2 and 3 etc etc. I'm not sure how you call your code.

However, you can try (a mix of objects and if-else):

```
const decideFn = ({ var1, var2, var3, i }) = {
    const decision = {
        1: {
            0: {
                cond(i) {
                    if (var3 === 'test') {
                        if (i === 0) 
                            endresult.push({id: i, content: '123'})
                        else if (i === 2) 
                            endresult.push({id: i, content: '124'})
                        else 
                            endresult.push({id: i, content: '125'})
                    }
                    else endresult.push({id: i, content: '125'})
                }
            },
            1: {
                cond(i) { 
                   endresult.push({id: i, content: '126'}) 
                }
            }
        }
        2: {
            0: {
                cond(i) {            
                    if (i === 0) 
                        endresult.push({id: i, content: '127'})
                    else if (i === 2) 
                        endresult.push({id: i, content: '128'})}
                },
            1: {
                cond(i) {
                    if (i === 0) 
                        endresult.push({id: i, content: '128'})
                    else if (i === 2) 
                        endresult.push({id: i, content: '129'}) 
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // usage
    // does i go in a loop ?
    // your qn needs more details. but i hope you get the idea
    decision[var1][var2].cond(i)

}
```

Ultimately, it really boils down to how you feel you understand the code best and how other devs will read your code but personally I think your switch statements are fine.

Objects may give more flexibility though.

Answer (score 0):

If in every case you are pushing to the same variable, I would consider creating a function whose sole job is determining the right value based on the variables.

This could look like this:

```
const getContentValue(var1, var2, var3, i) {
 if (var1 === 1) {
   if (var2 === 0) {
     if (var3 === 'test') {
       if (i === 0) return '123'
       if (i === 2) return '124'
       return '125'
   }
   if (var2 === 1) {
     return '126'
   }
 }
 if (var1 === 2) {
   if (var2 === 0) {
     if (i === 0) return '127'
     if (i === 2) return '128'
   }
   if (var2 === 1) {
     if (i === 0) return '128'
     if (i === 2) return '129'
   }
 }
}

endResult.push({ id: i, content: getContentValue(var1, var2, var3, i) })
```

(Code is untested.)

A few things to notice and a few principles to take away:

- The basic "decision structure" is the same, but simplified by using an `if` statement. Switching between cases is, in my opinion, something you do when you have a lot of cases, not when you are switching between two things. `if` statements work great when you are switching between two options. If you really are working with a bunch of cases, say your var1 could actually be 10+ different numbers, might be simpler to stick with a `switch`.
- If you look at the `switch` statement in your code, there is a lot that is the same for every case. One trick is to look at what changes in the answer for each case. `i` is the same. Only the numbers change. That's a good road to head down for simplifying things.
- I don't think it's intentional but you have two cases that result in the number 128. You can probably do some additional simplification. (Hard to know exactly because I know the sample data you have is not exactly the real data you are working with.) I comment because it's actually a good teaching moment -- if you have end cases that are identical, that is something to take a good look at.
- Note the similarities between the concepts of a `switch` statement and an `if` statement. In a function, if you have a return statement, it will act like the `break` of a `switch` statement. If you are returning after each `if` case, you will have the equivalent of a `default` case when you have enough information to know what to return. (For example, see the line that says `return '125'`. We know that if we get to this point, 125 should be returned.)